# Structure of force table

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

In school, they asked us to do a force table and to search about it on internet to know what to do.
The problem is that I searched for hours but I didn't understand the concept 100% since I am not finding websites that could give me information about what is it and how to make it, but they gave me instructions on how to use it. I need to know what does it exactly do and how can I make a one. Please any help?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at it here[Force Table](http://titan.bloomfield.edu/facstaff/dnicolai/Physics/Physics105/Experiments/force.htm) and either try to make it yourself or buy it (which I don't assume it will be expensive.)